# Will data in my new volume be encrypted if I mount it in my full disk encrypted system?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I've installed a Ubuntu 12.04 server with full disk encryption. Now, I added a new volume (a md volume, integrated by 2 hdd in RAID1), and mounted it at root of my encrypted file system.

Will data on that new volume be encrypted as well as in the main file system, or do I need to encrypt it separately?

Thanks,
Checho.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, encrypted directory is separate file system. When you mount new volume to this directory, you change file hierarchy tree but the encrypted file system is still separated from other ones.

So yes, you should singly encrypt each file system.

It's easy to test this. Create text file at simple volume, mount volume to encrypted directory. You'd see that you still can read text file right there, without decryption.